# google map marker drag event no working in android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am doing an android application contains multiple markers. I want to make marker long press event, I understand that `MarkerDragListener` can help me to do that. Here is the code I used for `MarkerDragListener`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady()");
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("System out", "onMarkerDragStart..."+arg0.getPosition().latitude+"..."+arg0.getPosition().longitude);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("System out", "onMarkerDragEnd..."+arg0.getPosition().latitude+"..."+arg0.getPosition().longitude);

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("System out", "onMarkerDrag...");
        }
    });

    mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
}
```

But Drag event not working for me, Someone please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from the [offlicial documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker):

> Markers are not draggable by default. You must explicitly set the marker to be draggable either with `MarkerOptions.draggable(boolean)` prior to adding it to the map, or `Marker.setDraggable(boolean)` once it has been added to the map.

meaning you have to make the marker **draggable** first, like this:

```
static final LatLng POSITION = new LatLng(-31.90, 115.86);
Marker marker = mGoogleMAp.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(PERTH)
                      .draggable(true));
```

after that you will observe your onMarkerDragStart(...) and onMarkerDragStart(...) callbacks invoked